# Where can I get a database of speech signals?

Tags: speech-processing

For a classification sort of experiment using Matlab, I am in need of a database of male and female voices. So where can I get links of such open databases.

Answer (score 3):

you can also find speech corpus from here

English:

[American National Corpus Open to All](http://www.americannationalcorpus.org/)

[Huge Corpus from Vox Forge Repository](http://www.repository.voxforge1.org/downloads/SpeechCorpus/Trunk/Audio/Main/8kHz_16bit/)

Indian Local:

[Hindi Language Corpus](http://tdil-dc.in/index.php?option=com_up-download&task=view-download-tool&view=GET&toolid=268)

[Bengali Corpus](http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~pabitra/shruti_corpus.html)

[Speeches from Indian Language Consortium](http://www.ldcil.org/)

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://festvox.org/cmu_arctic/ where you'll find a few voices of different genders and accents.  Some even have simultaneously recorded electroglottograph data too.

Comment: OK I will check that link.